# Unity – getting app to appear under "Open With" on iOS for a specific file-type

Tags: android, ios, unity-game-engine, file-type

I'm building with Unity / C#. I'd like my app to show up under "Open With" for a certain filetype, let's say OBJ, for iOS and hopefully Android. Once the app launches, I need to be able to retrieve the path of said OBJ so I can load it into the scene.

Has anyone tried this before, and if so, what methods and edits to editor / XCode settings would I use to make this work?

Is it even possible with a Unity app?